# While within while only fires once

Tags: php, while-loop, associative-array

I've stripped out some unnecessary code for simplicity.  I have two associative arrays. This code is supposed to generate four rows from array "tables" and display n cells from array "units. The first row is fine but second row onward do not display the units for some reason. Only key value used on Tables array at present.

Tables array =

```
    $tables = array( 
      'Delta'=> array('Available','1','2'),
      'Alpha' => array('Available','2','4'),
      'Bravo'=> array('Available','2','4'),
      'Charlie' => array('Available','4','6'),
      'Echo' => array('Available','4','6')
    );
```

Units array -

```
    $units = array (
    '00:00'  => '1' ,
    '00:15'  => '2' ,
    '00:30'  => '3' ,
    '01:00'  => '4' ,
    '01:15'  => '5' ,
    ...tl/dr


    echo "<table>";
    while( $tab = each( $tables ) ) 
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$tab[ 'key' ]."</td>";
        while( $element = each( $units ) ) 
            {
               echo "<td class='free'>".$element['key']."</td>";  
            }
        echo  "</tr>";  
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

Current results:

Delta   12:00   12:15   12:30   12:45   13:00   13:15   13:30   13:45....
Alpha

Bravo

Charlie

Echo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer with your code is to `reset()` the array pointer for `$units`, as on the first iteration of the outer loop `$units` will be iterated and reach the end:

```
while( $tab = each( $tables ) ) 
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$tab[ 'key' ]."</td>";

    reset($units);
    while( $element = each( $units ) ) 
        {
           echo "<td class='free'>".$element['key']."</td>";  
        }
    echo  "</tr>";  
    }
```

However `foreach()` will do this for you:

```
foreach( $tables as $tab ) 
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$tab[ 'key' ]."</td>";

    foreach( $units as $element ) 
        {
           echo "<td class='free'>".$element['key']."</td>";  
        }
    echo  "</tr>";  
    }
```

Comment: Oops. replied in wrong place. Excellent. That works fine. Didn't realise I had to reset it. I assumed that encountering the while again would reset it automatically. Many thanks